# Does Direct3D9 support quad primitives or not?

Tags: direct3d9

I read in the [Direct3D9 help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173490(VS.85).aspx) (emphasis mine) :

> Direct3D 9 supports points, lines, triangles, and grid primitives. These have been extended to support higher-order interpolation beyond linear. While triangles and lines have spatial extent, until now they were both rendered using linear interpolation. In Direct3D 9, Direct3D supports rendering of these primitive types using higher order, up to quintic, interpolation. **Furthermore, a new quad primitive type is now supported.** This new type can also be rendered with higher-order interpolation.

This leads me to believe that Direct3D9 supports quads, but I can't find anything resembling `D3DPT_QUADLIST` in the Direct3D9 include files, so is the help wrong, or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, I ran across this searching for something else.

Direct3D9 doesn't support Quad Lists, this may actually be early documentation, or perhaps documentation from another system (such as Xbox 360) That accidentally leaked over.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the even later reply, but I have a feeling someone coming from an OpenGL background will stumble onto this and get confused.

The actual reason that's there is because it was basically an early version of the tessellation shaders we now have in Direct3D 11. There was -very- little support for it, however, so it was very poorly documented and essentially dropped in D3D10.

If you're curious or want more information, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or do a search for "Using Higher-Order Primitives (Direct3D9) if the article's moved, as they so often seem to.